# Use MoveRotation to Look At Another Object Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Basically I am looking for a simple way for using the rigidbody/physics engine to have my ship look at another object (the enemy). I figured getting the direction between my transform and the enemy transform, converting that to a rotation, and then using the built in MoveRotation might work but it is causing this weird effect where it just kind of tilts the ship. I posted the bit of code as well as images of before and after the attempt to rotate the ship (The sphere is the enemy).

```
private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     //There is a user on the ship's control panel.
     if (user != null)
     {
         var direction = (enemyOfFocus.transform.position - ship.transform.position);
         var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);
         ship.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(rotation);
     }
 }
```

Before.
[image]
After.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) is a rotation about the given angles, for convenience provided as a `Vector3`.

Your direction is rather a vector pointing from `ship` towards `enemyOfFocus` and has a magnitude so the `x, y, z` values also depend on the distance between your objects. These are no Euler angles!

What you rather want is [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) (the example in the docs is basically exactly your use case ;) )

```
var direction = enemyOfFocus.transform.position - ship.transform.position;
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
ship.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(rotation);
```